# Codeigniter ignoring 'default_controller' route

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I've got a Codeigniter 3 site where all my routes work except my home page route, which is like so:

```
<?php
$route['default_controller'] = "front/homepage";
?>
```

If I create a new route as below I can access it as "/home" but nothing works for index. I get an error in my log as `404 Page Not Found: /index`, in my config i have index set to blank.

```
<?php
$route['home'] = "front/homepage";
?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no-longer supported in Codeigniter since V2 due to it being a bug in the routing logic.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#directories-and-default-controller-404-override